# Integrating to Workday Custom List Object via SOAP

Tags: api, soap, integration, workday-api

Running into issues building to a Workday Custom Object in SOAP. Have tried a few different ways, but my message continues to fail. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bsvc="urn:com.workday/bsvc" xmlns:cus="urn:com.workday/tenants/{tenant}/data/custom"> 
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
     <bsvc:Edit_Worker_Additional_Data_Request>
        <bsvc:Business_Process_Parameters>
           <bsvc:Auto_Complete>1</bsvc:Auto_Complete>
           <bsvc:Run_Now>1</bsvc:Run_Now>
        </bsvc:Business_Process_Parameters>
        <bsvc:Worker_Custom_Object_Data>
           <bsvc:Effective_Date>2018-05-04</bsvc:Effective_Date>
           <bsvc:Worker_Reference>
              <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="Employee_ID">XXXX</bsvc:ID>
           </bsvc:Worker_Reference>
           <bsvc:Business_Object_Additional_Data>
           <cus:additionalTerminationDetails>
           <!-- Here's the List Object that fails --> 
           <cus:nextSteps>
              <cus:nextSteps>
                  <cus:id cus:type"alias">XXX</cus:id>
              </cus:nextSteps>
           </cus:nextSteps>
           <!-- These work -->
                 <cus:nextEmployerIfKnown>XXXX</cus:nextEmployerIfKnown>
                 <cus:nextRoleIfKnown>Tester</cus:nextRoleIfKnown>
                 <cus:cobraStartDate>2018-MM-DD</cus:cobraStartDate>
                 <cus:cobraEndDate>2018-MM-DD</cus:cobraEndDate>
              </cus:additionalTerminationDetails>
           </bsvc:Business_Object_Additional_Data>
        </bsvc:Worker_Custom_Object_Data>
     </bsvc:Edit_Worker_Additional_Data_Request>
  </soapenv:Body>
```

EDIT: Had to alter the custom list call to get to the correct element.

Answer (score 0):

What is in the SOAP response?  Workday is usually pretty good about giving you error feedback.  Also, if you go to Workday Community and look at the Web Services API you can usually match up the error to the "Validation" notes for the XML element that failed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to community. Was able to solve the code though, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @WillFinnegan can you please share how you solved this issue?